# Can't access files directly in browser or with AJAX - Opencart Installation

Tags: php, ajax, apache, centos, opencart

I have a custom php script that I'm trying to access via AJAX, and i get a return of 404 in browser or via AJAX. I've been able to access custom scripts via PHP in the current environment. Strange? Here's my .htaccess file, i've tried editing a few things with no luck. CentOS 6.4. Google fu turns up nothing. Thanks in advance for any help. Permissions have been set to 777 to test with no luck either.

```
 # 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 

 # 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

 # For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

 Options +FollowSymlinks

 # Prevent Directoy listing 
 Options -Indexes

 # Prevent Direct Access to files
 <FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
 </FilesMatch>

 # SEO URL Settings
 RewriteEngine On
 # If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you    folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
 RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
 RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
 RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

 ### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
 ### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
 ### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following     settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are      getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of    product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200

# 7. disable open_basedir limitations
# php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

AJAX script starts like

```
  $.ajax({                                    
  url: '/phplibrary/dophp.php?make='+ thisValue +'', data: "", dataType: 'json',       success: function(rows)
```

Error in Chrome Dev:

```
 GET http://mydomain.com/phplibrary/dophp.php?make=Honda 404 (Not Found)
```

EDIT: The path does exist.

Comment: does 'http://caritect.com/phplibrary/dophp.php' exist? otherwise try adjusting your path.

Comment: probably try setting the ajax call to: $.ajax({                                    
  url: 'phplibrary/dophp.php?make='+ thisValue +'', data: "", dataType: 'json',       success: function(rows)

Comment: I've used this exact ajax script on another site, the formatting translated a little weird during the copy/paste to this site, but I know for a fact that end of it works.

Comment: @Nick the path does exist.

Comment: Do you have a `phplibrary` directory in your site's document root?If not, it won't get caught by the `-f` or `-d` rules, and get rewritten by the final rule that redirects everything to `index.php`.

Comment: @ Marc - I have a phplibrary folder in the root directory. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

can you check the URL with www like

http://www.mydomain.com/phplibrary/dophp.php?make=Honda

Based on the configuration, if the HTTP_SERVER is configured with WWW, then the URL without www may throw 404.

Cheers :)